# OpenBravo POS Sales Tax

Tags: openbravo

I am implementing openbravo pos in a local shop. They want the ability to be able to type in a price and have sales tax added automatically rather than using a PLU or UPC. Basically I need to apply an 8% sales tax to any item that is entered not using tax categories. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new Tax Category called "General" and set the Tax % as 8% for the same and then map the products where you do not have the Tax Information over there. So when the order it raised, it will pick up the 8% taxing. Hope that helps.

Thanks,
Shankar

Answer (score 0):

I add into my project set Tax Category by default. You can try my source code https://bitbucket.org/svininykh/openbravoposru